# Opening a Form Using Menu Strip

Tags: vb.net, winforms, menustrip

I am having trouble trying to open a form using a menu strip

I have tried adding a message box to see if its just a form however when trying this wont open neither

```
If DocumentCenterToolStripMenuItem.Selected = True Then
    MessageBox.Show("Testing", "Important Message")
End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double click on your menu item in the winforms designer. This creates a `Click` event handler in your form code.

```
Private Sub DocumentCenterToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
    Handles TestToolStripMenuItem.Click

    MessageBox.Show("Testing", "Important Message")
End Sub
```

Winforms applications are event driven. I.e., normally they are waiting for input. When you type a key or activate the mouse, events are risen. You can handle these events with event handler methods. Once such a method has terminated, the application is waiting again. They are like other methods but have a `Handles` keyword followed by the event designation.

Normally, you can not ask whether the menu item is selected with `If DocumentCenterToolStripMenuItem.Selected = True Then`, as probably this code is not even running, or when it is running, then probably the user is not clicking this menu item at this exact moment.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated !!